# Optimizing indexes for query on large table with multiple joins

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

We have an `images` table containing around ~25 million records and when I  query the table based on the values from several joins the planner's estimates are quite different from the actual results for row counts. We have other queries that are roughly the same without all of the joins and it is much faster. I would like to know what steps I can take to debug and optimize the query. Also, is it better to have one index covering all columns included in the join and the `where` clause or a multiple indexes one for each join column and then another with all of the fields in the `where` clause?

The query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT "images".* FROM "images" 
INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "images"."location_id" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "images"."creator_id" = "users"."id" 
INNER JOIN "user_groups" ON "users"."id" = "user_groups"."user_id" 
WHERE "images"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
AND "user_groups"."group_id" = 7 
AND "images"."creator_type" = 'User' 
AND "images"."status" = 2 
AND "locations"."active" = TRUE 
ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC 
LIMIT 50 
OFFSET 0;
```

The explain:

```
Limit  (cost=25670.61..25670.74 rows=50 width=585) (actual time=1556.250..1556.278 rows=50 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=25670.61..25674.90 rows=1714 width=585) (actual time=1556.250..1556.264 rows=50 loops=1)
        Sort Key: images.date_uploaded
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 75kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..25613.68 rows=1714 width=585) (actual time=0.097..1445.777 rows=160886 loops=1)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..13724.04 rows=1753 width=585) (actual time=0.069..976.326 rows=161036 loops=1)
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..214.87 rows=22 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.786 rows=22 loops=1)
                          ->  Seq Scan on user_groups  (cost=0.00..95.83 rows=22 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.570 rows=22 loops=1)
                                Filter: (group_id = 7)
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 5319
                          ->  Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.29..5.40 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=22)
                                Index Cond: (id = user_groups.user_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 18
                    ->  Index Scan using creator_date_uploaded_Where_pub_not_del on images  (cost=0.56..612.08 rows=197 width=585) (actual time=0.062..40.992 rows=7320 loops=22)
                          Index Cond: ((creator_id = users.id) AND ((creator_type)::text = 'User'::text) AND (status = 2))
              ->  Index Scan using locations_pkey on locations  (cost=0.43..6.77 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=161036)
                    Index Cond: (id = images.location_id)
                    Filter: active
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
Planning time: 1.694 ms
Execution time: 1556.352 ms
```

We are running Postgres 9.4 on an RDS db.m4.large instance.

Comment: You can try creating partial indexes for the specified values of column `images.creator_type` and `locations.active` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-partial.html Also check whether table statistics are up to date - the distribution of values could be off thus the planner makes wrong decisions.

Comment: I did make some adjustments to the planning statistics based on the full count vs distinct count and it helped very minorly. I'm not entirely sure how the distinct affect multi-column indexes though.  I have a few partial indexes but not for `creator_type`, does that one stand out as extra important to you? For the record 99% of the records are `creator_type = 'User'`.

Comment: In this case the partial index probably won't help much - its primary purpose is to exclude the most popular value(s) from the index because such a popular value will inevitably require full-table scan. The most important indexes here are for the JOIN-ed columns. You could try to filter by `creator_id IN (SELECT user_id from user_groups WHERE group_id = 7)` In my opinion it should be better to have multiple indexes - for each JOIN and for WHERE clauses.

Comment: .._not_del  index on first look looks too expensive, no need for "creator_type" column in that index . What happens if you only create index on and creator_id and status_id separately?. db.m4.large instance has only 8GB ram right? if that's the case size of indexes maters a lot, since it potentially wont fit and stay in ram. You might try to create a partial index like (("images"."status" = 2),"images"."creator_id" ) , you should also try to set column statistics on "creator_id" column to something like 10000, analyze table and see if something changes and planer gets better estimates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the query itself, the only thing you can do is skipping on `users` table. From `EXPLAIN` you can see that it only does an `Index Only Scan` without actually touching the table. So, technically your query could look like this:

```
SELECT images.* FROM images
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = images.location_id
INNER JOIN user_groups ON images.creator_id = user_groups.user_id
WHERE images.deleted_at IS NULL 
AND user_groups.group_id = 7 
AND images.creator_type = 'User' 
AND images.status = 2 
AND locations.active = TRUE 
ORDER BY date_uploaded DESC 
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 50
```

The rest is about indexes. `locations` seems to have very little data, so optimization here will gain you nothing. `user_groups` on the other hand could benefit from an index `ON (user_id) WHERE group_id = 7` or `ON (group_id, user_id)`. This should remove some extra filtering on table content.

```
-- Option 1
CREATE INDEX ix_usergroups_userid_groupid7
ON user_groups (user_id)
WHERE group_id = 7;

-- Option 2
CREATE INDEX ix_usergroups_groupid_userid
ON user_groups (group_id, user_id);
```

Of course, the biggest thing here is `images`. Currently, the planer would do an index scan on `creator_date_uploaded_Where_pub_not_del` which I suspect does not fully match the requirements. Here, multiple options come to mind depending on your usage pattern - from one where the search parameters are rather common:

```
-- Option 1
CREATE INDEX ix_images_creatorid_typeuser_status2_notdel
ON images (creator_id)
WHERE creator_type = 'User' AND status = 2 AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

to one with completely dynamic parameters:

```
-- Option 2
CREATE INDEX ix_images_status_creatortype_creatorid_notdel
ON images (status, creator_type, creator_id)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

The first index is preferable as it is smaller (values are filtered-out rather than indexed).

To summarize, unless you are limited by memory (or other factors), I would add indexes on `user_groups` and `images`. Correct choice of indexes must be confirmed empirically, as multiple options are usually available and the situation depends on statistical distribution of data.

Comment: I have the indexes mentioned on the `user_groups` table already. I didn't think about skipping the users join, Im using an ORM so Ill see about avoiding that. I have tried the two recommended indexes and they didn't seem to help me much, saved ~50ms in my testing.

Comment: I ended up using a subquery to get rid of a few of the joins, and that sped it up considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach:

I think one of the problems is that you are doing joins 1714 times, and then just returning the first 50 results. We'll probably want to avoid extra joins as soon as possible.

For this, We'll try to have an index by date_uploaded first. And then we will filter by the rest of the columns. Also, We add creator_id for getting an index-only scan:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_images_sort_test
ON images (date_uploaded desc, creator_id)
WHERE creator_type = 'User' AND status = 2 AND deleted_at IS NULL;
```

Also you may use the generic version (unfiltered). But it should somewhat worse. Since the first column will be date_uploaded we will need to read the whole index for the filtering of the rest of the columns.

```
CREATE INDEX ix_images_sort_test
ON images (date_uploaded desc, status, creator_type, creator_id)
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL;
```

The pity here is that you are also filtering by group_id, which is on another table. But even that, It may be worth trying this approach.

Also, verify that all joined tables have an index on the foreign key.

So, add an index for user_groups as (user_id, group_id)

Also, as Boris noticed, you may remove the "Users" join.